# Python Multiprocessing.Pool in a class

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

I am trying to change my code to a more object oriented format. In doing so I am lost on how to 'visualize' what is happening with multiprocessing and how to solve it. On the one hand, the class should track changes to local variables across functions, but on the other I believe multiprocessing creates a copy of the code which the original instance would not have access to. I need to figure out a way to manipulate classes, within a class, using multiprocessing, and have the parent class retain all manipulated values in the nested classes.

A simple version (OLD CODE):

```
function runMultProc():
    ...
    dictReports = {}
    listReports = ['reportName1.txt', 'reportName2.txt']
    tasks = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    for report in listReports:
        if report not in dictReports:
            dictReports[today][report] = {}
            tasks.append(pool.apply_async(worker, args=([report, dictReports[today][report]])))
        else:
            continue

    for task in tasks:
        report, currentReportDict = task.get()
        dictReports[report] = currentFileDict

function worker(report, currentReportDict):
    <Manipulate_reports_dict>
    return report, currentReportDict
```

NEW CODE:

```
class Transfer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.masterReportDictionary[<todays_date>] = [reportObj1, reportObj2]

    def processReports(self):
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        self.pool.map(processWorker, self.masterReportDictionary[<todays_date>])
        self.pool.close()
        self.pool.join()

    def processWorker(self, report):
        # **process and manipulate report, currently no return**
        report.name = 'foo'
        report.path = '/path/to/report'

class Report():
    def init(self):
    self.name = ''
    self.path = ''
    self.errors = {}
    self.runTime = ''
    self.timeProcessed = ''
    self.hashes = {}
    self.attempts = 0
```

I don't think this code does what I need it to do, which is to have it process the list of reports in parallel AND, as processWorker manipulates each report class object, store those results. As I am fairly new to this I was hoping someone could help.

The big difference between the two is that the first one build a dictionary and returned it. The second model shouldn't really be returning anything, I just need for the classes to finish being processed and they should have relevant information within them.
Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to share state across multiple processes (hence `multiprocessing`). This is non-trivial. Usually, it's best to just change to an approach that *doesn't require shared state*, which this doesn't seem like it should. Also, I don't think you mean *nested* classes...

Comment: "The big difference between the two is that the first one build a dictionary and returned it. The second model shouldn't really be returning anything, I just need for the classes to finish being processed and they should have relevant information within them. " And that is *precisely what you should be avoiding with `multiprocessing`*. You *had an approach that worked*, why don't you just use it? Object orientation isn't necessary, and actually makes this *harder*.

Comment: The big reason I wanted to use objects is because the actual code this is in reference to ends up passing a lot of things around to different functions. So I started off with three variables that the first function needed, then five that the next needed etc. 

I am not opposed to creating a new list of the results and returning the objects if that is a possibility, I don't need to have the list magically update after each report is processed. I just need a finished list of all reports with their manipulated values.

Comment: Then it should be pretty straightforward, build up a new `Report` object which you return *inside the function you pass to `pool.map`*

Comment: Just so I am understanding, self.pool.map(processWorker, self.masterReportDictionary[<todays_date>]) would become something like results = self.pool.map(processWorker, self.masterReportDictionary[<todays_date>]) which would store the results as they finished and then I would just need to return the object at the end of the processWorker?

Comment: Well, no, you cannot have a `self.masterReportDictionary`, **it needs to build the reports in the function then return them**. `pool.map` returns the *aggregated results* of the function in a list. So, just like `map(my_func, objects)`